# GameObject.Find does not work in Android build after reloading Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two Scenes in Unity. First one is for importing data from a binary file and after file is imported i create a gameobject with the coordinates i read from the binary file. I use `DontDestroyOnLoad` for this game object.

Then i load my second scene using [AsyncOperation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.html) and find my object using `GameObject.Find`. This works fine and i can find the object and do my operations. However, in my second scene i have a reset button with which i reload the same scene using `AsyncOperation`. When scene is reloaded `GameObject.Find` can not find my object. By the way this only happens in Android build. In Editor it finds the object there is no problem.

This is how i reload the scene my `ResetScene` function gets called when button is pressed.

```
void ResetScene()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadAsyncScene());
    }
    IEnumerator LoadAsyncScene()
    {
        AsyncOperation asyncLoad = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("ARSession");

        while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why this issue occurs or does anyone have a better idea for finding object? Since i create the object in runtime i feel like i have no option other than `GameObject.Find`. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Note:** I tried finding the object in `Start` and `OnLevelWasLoaded`. Both of them did not work.

I logged every game object in hierarchy using this:

```
        foreach (GameObject obj in Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
        {

                Debug.Log(obj.name);
        }
```

In initial load my the game object i created is logged but after i reloaded the scene my object is not loaded.

> I actually found the source of the problem. I was changing the parent
>   of my object from `null` to another object and apparently this causes
>   the issue. However, i do not know how to fix this because i must
>   change the parent i can't change that logic.

Comment: Can I see your unity log?

Comment: You can see it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2umu5bwgxj6uoo/Editor.log?dl=0)

Comment: Is that new parent maybe inactive when you use `Find` .. the variations of `Find` only return active and enabled objects/components!

Comment: No actually i was changing the parent of the object and since `DontDestroyOnLoad` can not be applied to child object, my object is destroyed but i do not know how to fix this. It does not solve the issue if i make parent `null` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution. I did not realize the problem is caused because of changing the parent when i asked the question.

> DontDestroyOnLoad only work for root GameObjects

Therefore, when i added a parent to my object my object is destroyed. Making the parent null alone was not enough. `DontDestroyOnLoad` has to be applied again. The solution i found was like this:

```
void ResetScene()
{ 
    test.transform.parent = null;
    DontDestroyOnLoad(test);
    StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
}
```

Comment: Well i had an ARCore session and i was anchoring the object. I had to disable that script so it can work in editor :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution anyway ;) but please next time try to add all required information to your question from the beginning.

Comment: I know i should have but i was trying to keep it minimal because it is a big project.